# Xbox Live Family Pack on multiple consoles

Tags: xbox-network

If we have 4 xbox's in our house (three in bedrooms and one in the living room), can we buy an Xbox live Family Pack for 12 months (you get 12 months for 4 accounts) and use one account on each Xbox (we already have three xbox live accounts we want to combine and use the fourth for the living room). I know that it would work on one console, but i didnt know if you could recover one of the child accounts back onto the individual xboxs and still have the membership time for each account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your Xbox Live membership travels with the account, not the console. So if you have a Gold Account signed into a console, you have Gold privileges on that console. You can recover that account on a different console and have Gold privileges.

This is also covered in the [Gold Family Pack FAQ](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Live/JoinLive/FamilyPackFAQ).

> Q: I have multiple consoles in my family. Does my Xbox LIVE Gold Family Pack have to reside only one of those consoles?
>
> A: When an individual is added to an Xbox LIVE Gold Family Pack, that person’s Xbox LIVE account must be on the same console as the primary account holder. However, once they are a part of your Xbox LIVE Gold Family Pack, that person could recover their account on a different console and still remain a part of the Family Pack, as long as they reside in the same country as the primary account holder.

Comment: If you are planning to use one or more memberships on multiple consoles in the house (sounds like a great house, by the way), you might consider investing in a memory card (for older 360s) or USB memory stick and saving the profile on that. You can then move the memory device to the console on which you want to play and have access to the profile without needing to recover it each time. (This is also useful if you visit friends and want to log in there.)

Comment: we are not too concerned about moving the accounts around, the extra account for the living room xbox is so if people come over they can play online on a different account (and not mess up our KDRs and world rankings on our individual xbox live accounts.) Thank you for your input though.